# Creando una interfaz gráfica para hacer un explorador de archivos

Tags: javascript, interfaz-gráfica

He empezado a montarme uno usando javascript, de momento me funciona a nivel de consola, pero me gustaría tener una interface gráfica y que pudieras interaccionar con la información a través del ratón. Al principio pensé en usar etiquetas para mostrar la información, pero debido a la naturaleza dinámica de esta, no puedo representar una información que va aumentando con una cantidad estática de etiquetas. Entonces he pensando en usar el Canvas, pero no sé si este me permite generar imágenes con las que pueda interactuar mediante ratón. **¿Alguien me recomienda algo? ¿Qué recursos de html, css o javascript podría usar? ¿Alguna librería en concreto de javascript?**
Por si no se me entiende bien, ahí va un pantallazo del explorador de windows ya que se trata de algo que se parece visualmente a lo que quiero hacer. Tengo que dibujar carpetas y tags.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado varios recursos para visualizar datos que al menos, simulen ser datos de ficheros:

- https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/orZlP
- https://codepen.io/enahom99/pen/MazNRV
- https://editor.datatables.net/
- https://datatables.net/

Comment: Y por cierto me doy cuenta que también podría usar etiquetas html para representar la información, creándolas estas de una manera dinámica. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/206020/error-generando-etiquetas-din%C3%A1micamente-a-trav%C3%A9s-de-javascript