# Error generando etiquetas dinámicamente a través de javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código, con el que pretendo generar etiquetas **h1**:

```
var labelArray = [];
function createlabel(){
 labelArray.push(document.createElement("h1"));
 document.body.appendChild(labelArray[-1]);
 labelArray[-1].style = "color: blue";
 labelArray[-1].value = "etiqueta de ejemplo";
}
createlabel();
```

Al ejecutarlo, me da un error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node':
>   parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Me da ese error en la sentencia: `document.body.appendChild(labelArray[-1]);`
¿Alguien sabe que significa y cómo puedo solventarlo?

Comment: ¿Por qué usar el índice -1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es el índice negativo en el array, basta con cambiarlo.

```js
var labelArray = [];
function createlabel(){
 labelArray.push(document.createElement("h1"));
 document.body.appendChild(labelArray[0]);
 labelArray[0].style = "color: blue";
 labelArray[0].innerHTML = "etiqueta de ejemplo";
}
createlabel();
```

```html
<body>
<p>hola</p>
</body>
```

Para crear varias etiquetas lo más cómodo es incluir un bucle en la función

```js
var labelArray=[];
function createlabels(n){
 for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
 labelArray.push(document.createElement("h1"));
 document.body.appendChild(labelArray[i]); 
 labelArray[i].style = "color: red";
 labelArray[i].innerHTML = "ejemplo"+i; 
 }
}
createlabels(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Veo 2 fallos en tu código el primero es que intentas asignar el nodo antes de modificar sus propiedades

```
 labelArray.push(document.createElement("h1"));
 document.body.appendChild(labelArray[-1]);
 labelArray[-1].style = "color: blue";
 labelArray[-1].value = "etiqueta de ejemplo";
```

Debería ser;

```
 labelArray.push(document.createElement("h1"));
 labelArray[-1].style = "color: blue";
 labelArray[-1].value = "etiqueta de ejemplo";
 document.body.appendChild(labelArray[-1]);
```

El siguiente error es que estás accediendo a una posición del array que no existe, el push se haría en tal caso en `labelArray[0]` como primera inserción.

```
var labelArray = [];
function createlabel(){
labelArray.push(document.createElement("h1"));

labelArray[0].style = "color: blue";
labelArray[0].value = "etiqueta de ejemplo";

 document.body.appendChild(labelArray[0]);
}
```

De esta manera si que creará tu elemento.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como crear elementos dinámicamente espero que te aporte la luz que necesitas;

```
var tablero=document.getElementById("tablero");

function DibujarTablero(ancho, alto){
let contador = 1;
for(let x=0;x<ancho;x++){

    let fila = document.createElement("p");
    fila.id ='col'+x;
    fila.onclick = click_Fila;
    fila.className='fila';
    for(let i=0;i<alto;i++){
    let celda = document.createElement("div");
    celda.className = "circulo";

    celda.id =contador++;

    celda.onclick = click_Celda; //el método de evento se asigna sin parentesis
    fila.appendChild(celda); //introduzco en fila la celda
    }
    tablero.appendChild(fila); //y la fila en el tablero
}
 casillas = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
}

DibujarTablero(7,6);
```